# My Appium Script is not running on Android 6.0.1 where it runs smoothly over Android 5.0.2

Tags: automation, webdriver, appium

I am New to Appium.

My Script is not Working For Nexus 5(Android 6.0.1)/MI Note3(6.0.1), Where it runs smoothly over Lenovo A6000(Android 5.0.2). Why?

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");

        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","5.0.2");//For Nexus5 it is 6.0.1
        String apkpath="Location of 'myApp.apk'";
        capabilities.setCapability("app", apkpath);
         //app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "4fa1b92f");//or 'Nexus 5'
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

        capabilities.setCapability("app-package", myAppPackage);
        driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
System.out.println("Successfuly launched");
driver.findElement(By.id("com.********.******:id/btn_login")).click();
```

On Nexus5/MI it gives

`RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: com.******.******/com.********.MainActivity or com.*******.******.com.*******.*******.MainActivity never started (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information`

Exception.
 This Exception comes on "Driver Initialization" line

Please help me, What settings or capabilities I Have to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Update in following file :
C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib
\adb.js

In Line no 1041
**Update ((outline.indexOf(name) !== -1) to if ((outline.indexOf(name) !== -1) && !(outline.indexOf("bad pid") > -1))**

Comment: **@shiv** There is no Line No. 1041 in **adb.js**. It has only Three Lines.

Comment: There will be two adb.js files in Appium - One is having only three lines and second is bigger one. Please search adb.js under appium folder and try.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib is the path where you will get this file ...  "adb.js"

Comment: Thanks @shiv. Got it. Will Try and Let you know if there is any problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected if you have the older version of Android SDK which supports OS till 5.0. **Update your Android SDK** using SDK manager then it should work.

You can install the packages by opening the SDK manager and it will automatically select the required packages. You just need to click on "Install Packages" button.